# Need neutral out at my well house but only have 220 v

Tags: electrical

I have 220v to my well house but need to install a 120v convenience receptacle for maintenance tools. The feed coming from my main panel is direct burial. What can I do ?

Comment: What size is the cable and breaker?

Comment: How much power is needed ?  What voltage ? 110 120? More? I assume the cost of the fix must be less than a battery operated inverter

Comment: What is present at the pump house for a disconnecting means?  Is there room in there for another breaker? Also, is there a grounding electrode system at this pump house?

Comment: Also, how long is this feed?

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is what can I do without running a new line?

My question is do you have a grounding wire with the 220V? Because if you don't you are going to have to ground that circuit also.

Other than that you could set a small panel, split your circuits and add a buck transformer to provide you with 120V from your 220V feeder, and your going to have to ground one secondary side of the line. If you are using an autotransformer configuration the ground should be on the isolated phase of the secondary.

If all of this is a little much experience wise, I would recommend you contact a licensed electrician.

Good luck.

Comment: Depending on distance and the existing wire size creating a seperatly derived system using a transformer can save a bunch, but if it is not a long run installing a new feeder may be cheaper.

Answer (score -1):

If your wire is 4-wire (L1+L2+N+E) just connect the N wire if you don't want to replace current wire you could:

> install a step-down transformer (you should connect also to ground one of secondary coils and add a breaker on the secondary)
>   fit earthing pole, and just use the current PE conductor as neutral (it was allowed till about mid 90's, at least for ovens).

Comment: You absolutely cannot use the protective Earth wire as neutral. I don't care if you've seen it done with ovens, that is a special case and you do not understand the special circumstances there. OP said there is no neutral wire  present.

Comment: To be honest this answer is gibberish.  You start talking about 4 wire... and the go on to something that makes no sense whatsoever.  The purpose of the question is because OP doesn’t have 4 wires, he has either 2 or 3 and hasn’t yet clarified.